# A question involving finding values in integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let p(x) be a continuous function such that $\int_2^3{p(x)}dx$=$c\cdot\int_0^2{p(\frac{x+4}{2}})dx$ then find the value of c?

I am thinking of dividing the integral on the left hand side into two parts but i have no idea of how to get that ($\frac{x+4}{2}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use substitution $\frac{x+4}{2}=u\\$ when $$x=0 \rightarrow u=\frac{0+4}{2}=2\\x=2 \rightarrow u=\frac{2+4}{2}=3\\du=\frac{1}{2}dx\\\int_{0}^{2}f(\frac{x+4}{2})dx=\int_{2}^{3}f(u)2du=2\int_{2}^{3}f(u)du$$now $c$ equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Let $t=\frac{x+4}{2}$ in the second part. it is easy to get $c=\frac12$.

Comment: Beat me to it! $\,$